# Find Element wrapped in a HTML tag

Tags: jquery

If i have the following HTML structure, how would i grab the text between the strong tag within the h2 element.

```
<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2>
   <h2>
     <strong>Default</strong>
     <span class="default">(Default)</span>
     <a class="remove remove-stage-1" href="#">Remove</a>
     <span class="remove remove-stage-2 hidden">
  </h2>
```

At the moment i am trying things in the console and have come up with

```
template = $('.div1')
$(template).find('h2').each(function(index, elem) {
  console.log(index + $(this).text(), elem + $(this).text() );
});
```

Which will output my elem as

```
Default (Default) Remove
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*how would i grab the text between the strong tag within the h2 element.*

You don't need `.each`

```
template = $('.div1')
template.find('h2 strong').text()
```

Comment: using .each as there are multiple classes of .div1, only used one for this example, thank you for the answer, didn't realise it was such a simple tweak

Comment: @Richlewis, Agree If you have multiple classes of `.div1`, then you have to use `each`

Answer (score 2):

Use [Child Selector (“parent > child”)](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) selector.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4r3jU/1/)**

```
$('.div2 > h2 > strong').text()
```

**Description:** Selects all direct child elements specified by "child" of elements specified by "parent".

> The child combinator (E > F) can be thought of as a more specific form
>   of the descendant combinator (E F) in that it selects only first-level
>   descendants.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.div2 > h2 > strong').text();
```

Answer (score 1):

why not

```
template = $('.div1')
var text $(template).find('h2 strong').text();
```

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
$('.div2  h2').find("strong").text();
```

or

```
$('.div2  h2 strong').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
alert($('.div1 .div2 h2 strong').text());
```